# Building Lollipop AOSP source on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, android-5.0-lollipop

Do you have experience building AOSP lollipop on AWS?

What type of EC2 instance to use?

How long does it take?

Would a higher grade instance + SSD really speeding things up?

How's the experience of using this:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00HZ3NSPE/ref=_ptnr_aosp2_prweb_

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

make without -j option, it took 6 hours to completely build the tree.
spec: c3.8xlarge, 150GB HDD.  The tree may take 72GB.
ubuntu 14.4 LTS, jdk 7.

suggestions: use "screen" to toggle between screen.  pipe the output to a file so you can tail on the other screen to monitor the progress.

`make -j8  > result.txt 2>&1`

Source code download time could be long - and Android AOSP download seems to break the network connection often.  So you may want to somehow get your source first to S3 before transferring to your instance.

Because of the setup, I also created a snapshot so I can restart my image - because I don't want to setup the libraries such as libxml2:i386, libQt, jdk 7, etc.